# Unexpected behavior of the "Money" field in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I started developing a web sistem using Linux Ubuntu and at some point I had to do the following with the data type "money":

```
explode(" ", "R$ 3,000.00"); // [0] => "R$" and [1] => "3,000.00"
```

However when I installed the software in Windows I realized that the data is saved without space, that is, **"R$3,000.00"**. Soon, the code snippet fails to function properly.

Note: 1 could "fix" this using:

```
preg_replace("/[R$]+/", "$0 $1", "R$3,000.00"); // "R$ 3,000.00"
```

But certainly not a better way.

Note 2: The version of PostgreSQL used is 9.5

Would anyone have any suggestions for resolving this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what's your `lc_monetary`?.., also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Money type comes from the age when applications were ran by databases and stored procedures had to format currency correctly. This is not true any more and the use of the `money` data type is now discouraged. You should use decimal instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that the `lc_monetary` locale does not have the same value on both computers. This is what you have an "Unexpected behavior" on two different operating systems.

You can change the `lc_monetary` locale with:

```
set lc_monetary to 'SOME_LOCALE';
```

Then test it with:

```
test=# SELECT 34.888::money;
 money  
--------
 $34.89
(1 row)
```

Read more at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MONETARY

If your application is using different OS, it is wise to set the locale correctly at the beginning of the connection or in the configuration.

On Mac/Linux you can see available locales with `locale -a`. I an not sure for Windows.

If you don't generally use the currency symbol you should definitively consider to store the number as a `decimal` instead.